# what does the `-e` switch do from the bash shebang

Tags: bash

What does the `-e` flag do at the bash shebang?

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

Clearly it's a flag but not clear what it is.

e.g. at the head of a script.

Comment: Did you check the man page?

Comment: Related reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: @Steve yes. I couldn't find anything about it being used at a shebang. There was something about it being used as a conditional expression but didn't seem applicable. i.e. "-e file
              True if file exists."

Answer (score 2):

from `man bash`:

```
 -e      Exit  immediately  if a pipeline (which may consist of a
                      single simple command), a list, or  a  compound  command
                      (see  SHELL  GRAMMAR above),  exits with a non-zero sta‐
                      tus.  The shell does not exit if the command that  fails
                      is  part  of  the  command  list immediately following a
                      while or until keyword, part of the test  following  the
                      if  or elif reserved words, part of any command executed
                      in a && or || list  except  the  command  following  the
                      final  && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last,
                      or if the command s return value is being inverted  with
                      !.   If a compound command other than a subshell returns
                      a non-zero status because a command failed while -e  was
                      being  ignored, the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR,
                      if set, is executed before the shell exits.  This option
                      applies to the shell environment and each subshell envi‐
                      ronment separately (see  COMMAND  EXECUTION  ENVIRONMENT
                      above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing
                      all the commands in the subshell.
If a compound command or shell function  executes  in  a
                  context  where -e is being ignored, none of the commands
                  executed within the compound command  or  function  body
                  will  be  affected  by the -e setting, even if -e is set
                  and a command returns a failure status.  If  a  compound
                  command  or  shell function sets -e while executing in a
                  context where -e is ignored, that setting will not  have
                  any  effect  until  the  compound command or the command
                  containing the function call completes.
```

**so, if there is an error it will exit right away.**

Answer (score 0):

> Use set -o errexit (a.k.a. set -e) to make your script exit when a command fails.

Please, refer to these articles to get more information about writing good bash scripts:

- http://kvz.io/blog/2013/11/21/bash-best-practices/
- http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/

Comment: So using it at the shebang is the same as `set -e`?

Comment: Yep, it works the same: `bash -e -c "echo 'This is the first message'; false; echo 'You cant see me.'"`:
>> This is the first message